# List comprehension causes memory to exceed

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

The problem statement is to rearrange an array alternatively with O(1) extra space.

**Eg. input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 | output: 6 1 5 2 4 3**

I've used multiplication modulo method as the input is in sorted order. I get a memory error on using list comprehension and map function while solving this problem in geekforgeeks.

https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/-rearrange-array-alternately/0/

The code in which I'm getting memory error on using list comprehension

```py
tCount = int(input())
while(tCount != 0):
    N = int(input())
    arr = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    start = 0
    end = N - 1
    c = arr[-1] + 1
    for itr in range(N):
        if itr % 2 == 0:
            arr[itr] = (arr[end] % c) * c + (arr[itr] % c)
            end -= 1
        else:
            arr[itr] = (arr[start] % c) * c + (arr[itr] % c)
            start += 1

    for num in arr:
        print(num // c, end = ' ')
    print()
    tCount -= 1
```

I've tried using this instead of list comprehension and the memory error still persists.

```py
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

The error message

```
Runtime ErrorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/34c5f82513bb97088693a8d8284ef014.py", line 4, in <module>
    arr = [int(num) for num in input().split()]
  File "/home/34c5f82513bb97088693a8d8284ef014.py", line 4, in <listcomp>
    arr = [int(num) for num in input().split()]
MemoryError
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/.................
```

The memory error vanished only on using this:

```py
arr = input().split()
for itr in range(N):
    arr[itr] = int(arr[itr])
```

Comment: If I remove the while loop, the code runs with an input of `6,1 2 3 4 5 6` and produces `6 1 5 2 4 3`. No memory error.

Comment: @PatrickArtner please check my answer and suggest should I delete it or not??

Comment: @PatrickArtner I was told `zip` space complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: @PatrickArtner The memory constraints are given while solving this problem in geeksforgeeks. The link to the question https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/-rearrange-array-alternately/0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one for loop to achieve the output you wanted. Works for only even-sized lists.

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
n=len(a)//2
for x,y,i in zip(a[:n],a[n:][::-1],range(0,(2*n)+1,2)): #x=[1,2,3],y=[6,5,4],i=0,2,4
    a[i]=y
    a[i+1]=x
print(a)
```

output:

```
[6,1,5,2,4,3]
```

**Generic code** (works fine for both even-sized lists and odd-sized lists).

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
n=len(a)//2
last=a[n]
for x,y,i in zip(a[:n],a[n:][::-1],range(0,(2*n)+1,2)): #x=[1,2,3],y=[7,6,5],i=0,2,4
    a[i]=y
    a[i+1]=x
if len(a)%2 ==1:
    a[-1]=last


print(a)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[7, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4]
```

> **NOTE** : space complexity of `zip` is O(n).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205045/discussion-on-answer-by-ch3ster-list-comprehension-causes-memory-to-exceed).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this took the most part of my morning! I hope this was not an interview question, if it was one, I would have failed...

So, the best I could come up with **tested only for even number of elements in list**:

- We use two pointers: `a` and `b`
- Both pointers walk the list backwards
- `a` starts from the last element
- `b` starts from the **first** element and walks circularly backwards (next index is `len - 1`)
- We iterate with step 2 (pos=0, 2, 4,...)
- In every step we do two swaps:

  - All swaps until the last one are `b <=> pos+1` and `a <=> pos` in order
  - The last swap overwrites a, so we change it a bit to `a <=> pos` and `b <=> a`
- Finally, we are left with the two last elements in wrong order, so swap them and we are done

(Note that I came up with the swaps experimentally and by writing the iterations on paper)

We have:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
# l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
len_l = len(l)

# We move a from the back to the front
a = len_l - 1

# We move b from the back to the front BUT start from 0, len-1, len-2, etc
b = 0

# There will always be this number of steps
for i in range(len_l//2 - 1):
    # We always increment by 2
    cur_pos = i * 2


    print(f"Starting  {i}, a={a}, b={b}, cur_pos={cur_pos}: {l}")

    # no swapping conflict
    if cur_pos + 1 != a:
        # Swap (order matters for 1st iteration):
        #      b <> cur_pos + 1
        #      a <> cur_pos
        l[b], l[cur_pos + 1] = l[cur_pos + 1], l[b]
        l[a], l[cur_pos] = l[cur_pos], l[a]
    else:
        # Swap (our last one):
        #     a <> cur_pos
        #     b <> a
        l[a], l[cur_pos] = l[cur_pos], l[a]
        l[b], l[a] = l[a], l[b]

    print(f"Finishing {i}, a={a}, b={b}, cur_pos={cur_pos}: {l}")

    # Now, decrement both pointers
    if b == 0:
        b = len_l - 1
    else:
        b -= 1

    a -= 1

print("Swapping last two positions")
# Now swap the last 2 elements
l[-2], l[-1] = l[-1], l[-2]
print(f"** Result: {l}")
```

The results are:

```
$ python3 ./test2.py
Starting  0, a=5, b=0, cur_pos=0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Finishing 0, a=5, b=0, cur_pos=0: [6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2]
Starting  1, a=4, b=5, cur_pos=2: [6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2]
Finishing 1, a=4, b=5, cur_pos=2: [6, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4]
Swapping last two positions
** Result: [6, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

and for a larger array (cause my first attempt failed there):

```
$ python3 ./test2.py
Starting  0, a=7, b=0, cur_pos=0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Finishing 0, a=7, b=0, cur_pos=0: [8, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2]
Starting  1, a=6, b=7, cur_pos=2: [8, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2]
Finishing 1, a=6, b=7, cur_pos=2: [8, 1, 7, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4]
Starting  2, a=5, b=6, cur_pos=4: [8, 1, 7, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4]
Finishing 2, a=5, b=6, cur_pos=4: [8, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
Swapping last two positions
** Result: [8, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5]
```

Note: I think with minor modification it could support odd elements but you need to define the behaviour

Comment: nice answer. Deserves upvote. Sometimes I tend to overthink skipping minor details. Great answer. Cheers. And take a look at how I dealt with odd-sized list.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this solves your problem in O(1) of memory:

```
>>> for x in xrange(10) :
...     a = range(x)    # use list(range(x)) for python3
...     print [a[-i/2-1] if i & 1 == 0 else a[i/2] for i in xrange(len(a))]
... 
[]
[0]
[1, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
[3, 0, 2, 1]
[4, 0, 3, 1, 2]
[5, 0, 4, 1, 3, 2]
[6, 0, 5, 1, 4, 2, 3]
[7, 0, 6, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
[8, 0, 7, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Even and odd-sized lists included. No `zip()` =)

Comment: it would really helpful if breakdown your code and explain it. Beginners like myself wouldn't understand this brilliant code.

Comment: @Ch3steR no problem. first two lines are for testing purpose, create an ordered list using `range()`. then comes a simple comprehension that iterates over the number of the elements in the list and takes the element from one (`a[i/2]`) or another (`a[-i/2-1]`) end of the list, depending on `i` being odd or even (`if i & 1 == 0`). if you have any particular questions, I'd be glad to answer.

Comment: I understood and thanks for taking out your time and explaining. Nice pythonic solution.

Answer (score 0):

I put it like this

```
input_ = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
a = input_[0:int(len(input_)/2)]
b = input_[len(a):int(len(input_))]
b.reverse()
count = 0
s =[]

if len(b)>len(a):
    a.append(None)

for x in b:
    s.append(x)
    s.append(a[count])
    count += 1

print(s)
```